# What's the easiest way to find multiple unused local ports withing a range?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

What I need is to find unused local ports withing a range for further usage (for appium nodes). I found this code:

```
getPorts() {
        freePort=$(netstat -aln | awk '
      $6 == "LISTEN" {
        if ($4 ~ "[.:][0-9]+$") {
          split($4, a, /[:.]/);
          port = a[length(a)];
          p[port] = 1
        }
      }
      END {
        for (i = 7777; i < 65000 && p[i]; i++){};
        if (i == 65000) {exit 1};
        print i
      }
    ')
    echo ${freePort}
}
```

this works pretty well if I need singe free port, but for parallel test execution we need multiple unused ports. So I need to modify the function to be able to get not one free port, but multiple (depends on parameter), starting from the first found free port and then store the result in one String variable. For example if I need ports for three 3 devices, the result should be:
7777 7778 7779

the code should work on macOS, because we're using mac mini as a test server.

Since I only started with bash, it's a bit complicated to do for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a `bash` code, it works fine on Linux, so if your Mac also runs `bash` it will work for you.

```
getPorts() {
    amount=${1}
    found=0
    ports=""
    for ((i=7777;i<=65000;i++))
    do
        (echo > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/${i}) >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
            #echo "${i}"
            ports="${ports} ${i}"
            found=$((found+1))
            if [[ ${found} -ge ${amount} ]]
            then
                echo "${ports:1}"
                return 0
            fi
        }
    done

    return 1
}
```

Here is how to use use it and the output:

```
$ getPorts 3
7777 7778 7779

$ getPorts 10
7777 7778 7779 7780 7781 7782 7783 7784 7785 7786
```

Comment: Thank you @Azize, work as expected! One question, can you explain what this if is for? ```if [[ ${found} -ge ${amount} ]]```

Comment: To check if the amount of port you want is equal or great than the ones found. Otherwise it will not stop and would show you all  available ports.

Comment: what is the best way  to have all ports in one line as one String variable like 7777 7778 7779 etc ?

Comment: Thank you, it was mega helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Finding unused ports from 5000 to 5100:

```
range=(`seq 5000 5100`)
ports=`netstat -tuwan | awk '{print $4}' | grep ':' | cut -d ":" -f 2`
echo ${range[@]} ${ports[@]} ${ports[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: What Azize suggested is the best option for me. But I have a question regarding how to parse the result string? So the result is a String: 7777 7778 7779. What I need is to go through the this string and get ports one by one. What I was trying is this: ```for ((i=0;i<$#;i++)) {
        echo $#
        current_port=$(echo ${global_portList} | awk -v a="${i+1}" '{print $a}')
        echo ${current_port}
    } ```  but this returns 7779 7779 7779 three times . I think something wrong with awk expression. So the result of every loop iteration should be next port from the result String

Comment: @DimaZeuge: How the script works: Define an array of numbers in desired range. Define an array of used ports. Get the `diff` of those two arrays.

Comment: @DimaZeuge: Regardiing your question, put the string in parenthesis and it becomes an array. Then iterate the array.